# Intercept incoming HTTP request

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I am working on application which uses SSO for authentication. Our Angular 5 application is deployed on IIS server. So whenever user enters URL we are redirecting them to SSO login page from IIS server, then they will authenticate themselves and be redirected to actual application home page. Here we want to capture/intercept few header information of HTTP request when it redirected to home page of the application.

I have gone through HttpInterceptor in Angular 5, where it is given that interceptors will transform the outgoing request. it is there any possibility to intercept incoming request?

Comment: That *"incoming request"* doesn't go to the Angular app at all; it goes to IIS, which responds with the content of `index.html`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the inputs, is there is anyway to approach or suggestions solve this problem statement.

Comment: @vinnus did you solve for this?

Comment: @jordan we wrote .net code intercept the http request